# Angular2: Referencing configurable module from other modules

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular-module

My main `AppModule` has recently grown significantly so I want to cut it into multiple smaller modules. As the first step, I took a number of login / registration components and placed them in `LoginModule`. There is one problem, though. Components that I've placed in `LoginModule` depends on another module that is declared and configured in the main `AppModule`. This required module accepts a number of configuration parameters and of course, I'd like to have it configured in one single place.

As an example, let's take `IonicModule` but this question is Angular2-generic.

My main `AppModule` imports `IonicModule` and `LoginModule` as well as provides a number of parameters to the `IonicModule`.

```
imports: [
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
    mode: 'ios',
    tabsPlacement: 'bottom'
  }),
  LoginModule
]
```

Because all components in `LoginModule` depends on `IonicModule` I need to import `IonicModule` there as well. What should I do with configuration parameters, though? I'd like to avoid copy-pastying them from `AppModule`.

Is `imports: [IonicModule]` in this case enough? Or do I need to extract configuration parameters somewhere and inject them every time I refer `IonicModule` ?

All other modules that I will extract, will need to have `IonicModule` imported as well.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [IonicModule],  
  declarations: [
    (...)
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    (...) 
  ],
  providers: (...)
})
export class LoginModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Core Module

What you're looking for is to create a core module which [is recommended](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#core-for-root) by the official Angular Style Guide.

Here is how you can refactor your app to meet the style guide, keep all of your config in one place, and create a very organized and lean app:

### 1. Create a [Core Module](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#the-core-module)

To reduce root folder clutter create a Core Module that we **import *once* when the app starts** and *never import anywhere else*.

#### Steps:

- create an `app/core` folder
- move root services and components from `app/` to `app/core` (e.g. IonicModule)
- create a CoreModule class to own the core material

#### Example:

```
import {
  ModuleWithProviders, NgModule,
  Optional, SkipSelf }       from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }      from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { ExampleComponent }    from './example.component';
import { ExampleService }       from './example.service';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      mode: 'ios',
      tabsPlacement: 'bottom'
    })
  ],
  declarations: [ ExampleComponent ],
  exports:      [ ExampleComponent ]
})
export class CoreModule {
}
```

- **Remember**: Any module that you need to be available app-wide that uses a `forRoot()` method only needs to be imported once into the `CoreModule`. After doing this, it will be available to every module in your app.

### 2. Add Providers to `CoreModule` (forRoot)

Put this in the `CoreModule` class:

```
static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
  return {
    ngModule: CoreModule,
    providers: [
      ExampleService
    ]
  };
}
```

This is the *only* place you should put app-wide singleton providers. Do not place them in a [SharedModule](https://angular.io/styleguide#04-10).

### 3. Import the `CoreModule` into the `AppModule`

Add `CoreModule.forRoot()` to your `AppModule` imports like this:

```
imports: [
  AppRoutingModule,      
  BrowserModule,
  CoreModule.forRoot()
],
```

> Call `forRoot` only in the root application module, `AppModule`. Calling it in any other module, particularly in a lazy loaded module, is contrary to the intent and is likely to produce a runtime error.

### 4. [Prevent reimport](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#prevent-reimport-of-the-_coremodule_) of `CoreModule` (optional, but recommended)

At this point everything should work, but it's a best practice to prevent reimporting the `CoreModule`. This is especially helpful when working with others because another developer may not be fully aware of how a `CoreModule` should be used.

Add this to your `CoreModule`'s class:

```
constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
  throwIfAlreadyLoaded(parentModule, 'CoreModule');
}
```

## Further considerations

- **`Lazy-loaded routes`** Consider [creating lazy-loaded routes](https://angular.io/styleguide#04-13). This way the initial load of your app can be faster by only loading what is required by the current route.
- **[`SharedModule`](https://angular.io/styleguide#04-10)** Consider creating a `SharedModule` that does not include app-wide services. You can put components in here that will be required by certain routes, but not all routes.
- **`Why?`** The purpose of this is that if you load a lazy-loaded route that does not require a component of the shared service it will not download if that is the first route requested when the app first loads. This will speed up your initial app loading time. Of course, if a route is called that needs it, then the component will be available as expected.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. Unfortunately, there is something I can't completely understand. If I introduce `CoreModule` importing `IonicModule` and import `CoreModule` to `AppModule`, my `LoginModule` will still not see an `IonicModule`. Isn't it? This is exactly the same situation I have except that following your answer, I will add yet one, parent-level module (`CoreModule`)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at shared modules section [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#shared-module)

Theoretically,you could set the common dependancy modules in one module , export from there and import that. That way you could still set the parameters in one place. 
However , I havent tried doing this with a module that takes the app component in forRoot.

```
@NgModule({ imports: [IonicModule.forRoot(),//other deps with parameters], 
declarations: [ (...) ], entryComponents: [ (...) ], 
providers: (...) ,
exports:[//export deps]})
 export class commonModule {}
```

Hope it helps